# Postman not launching anymore in 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I downloaded postman tar from the official website and extracted the files, just like I did it the exact same way when I was using Ubuntu 16.04. Extracting is working but When I want to launch the application by double clicking the executable, it is not responding. While in 16.04 it would then launch Postman. I'm not getting any errors, just no reaction. I tried the x64 and x86 versions but that made no difference.

Comment: `Postman-linux-x64-6.0.10.tar.gz`.  No guarantee that an executable can be clicked / double clicked with any OS. .... ... Please do the command  `./Postman` In a terminal → If any errors, they should appear as text. ( I get this : "ORM initialization successful", etc.)

Comment: Launching in a terminal gave me the error in the answer that was provided. I can now launch it in terminal and by clicking.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem on a clean 18.04 install, the library `libgconf2-4` could not be found.

Try `sudo apt install libgconf2-4`, it should solve your problem.

Comment: didn't work for me, ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: not solved with this way

Comment: unfortunately didn't work :(

Answer (score 6):

Slight change to the answer provided by @Stanko worked for me.

Try adding hypen(-) in between libgconf and 2

`sudo apt install libgconf-2-4`

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 19.04. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In my case previous solution wasn't enough. I had to run:

```
killall _Postman
killall Postman
```

This will terminate all lingering Postman processes

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! Postman client was freezing and refusing to open new collections

Comment: if not, try killall postman

Answer (score 0):

After `sudo apt install libgconf2-4` I also needed to give permissions to the /home/yourusername/.config/Postman/ folder. Then it worked like a charm.

Comment: I have no Postman directory in ~/.config