# Can't get Postman installed and working on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I verified that I am running Ubuntu 18.04 by running:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I tried installing from the Ubuntu software app and it seems to install but running `postman` from the command line does nothing and clicking launch from the software app page for Postman only opens a terminal window for a brief instance then it disappears and Postman does not launch, Postman also does not show when I hit the button to search for apps.

I tried installing Postman from the command line but that doesn't work:

```
~$ sudo apt install postman
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postman
```

There is another way I've installed it which gets me further but still to no avail. I can follow the tutorial here https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/postman-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-1604/ which is how I installed successfully in Ubuntu 17. When I install it this way in 18.04 and run `postman` from the command line it launches the app but it only shows the loading icon and never actually starts working. The output from the command line is:

```
~$ postman
ORM initialization successful
App events bus { name: 'booted', namespace: 'shared' }
App events bus { data: {}, name: 'booted', namespace: 'requester' }
```

I have also tried the solution found on [Postman not launching anymore in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031534/postman-not-launching-anymore-in-18-04) and installed `libgconf2-4` but that didn't work.

Comment: did you find a wy to solve this?

Answer (score 10):

Download postman for Linux from the following link.

[Postman - Downloads](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

Open a terminal and then go to the directory where you downloaded the application. Check the filename; in my case, it was `Postman-linux-x64-6.2.4.tar.gz`. Now execute the following commands.

```
sudo tar -xzf Postman-linux-x64-6.2.4.tar.gz
rm Postman-linux-x64-6.2.4.tar.gz
sudo mv Postman /opt/Postman
sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman
```

Now, you can run Postman by entering `postman` in the terminal. Later you can make a desktop entry for it.

Comment: I didn't put it in opt, I kept it in my user/work/Postman folder since it's a portable app anyway.  I was the only user that had a need for it on the local machine, and I could just export all the settings into user/work/project/Postman and keep them in version control without paying for Pro to share it.

Comment: very good answer, thank you! (ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: May I ask what last command does exactly and why is it needed?I am new to linux and finding it real hard to install softwares compared to windows. Every software is installed to be in a diff way, it seems.

Comment: @Mandroid It creates a link in the `/usr/bin` folder. This folder is in the path variable when bash is started. So, by doing this you can run `postman` directly from the terminal; you won't need the full path to the postman executable.

Answer (score 6):

Postman is available as snap.You should try

```
sudo snap install postman
```

[image]

If you don't have snap installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

If this is launched, manage required permission from software center.

[image]

[Click here to know more about snap](https://docs.snapcraft.io/core/install-ubuntu)

It is also available as flatpak. If you have flatpak enabled, you can also install it from software center.

To install flatpak

```
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Using a web browser, download Postman from https://app.getpostman.com/app/download/linux64 to the default download directory (`~/Downloads` which is equivalent to `/home/<username>/Downloads`) where `<username>` is your Ubuntu username. Note: this assumes you have the 64-bit version of Ubuntu installed
2. You should now have the file `~/Downloads/Postman-linux-x64-6.2.4.tar.gz` or similar (the version may be different)
3. Make the directory `~/Software` (open a terminal and enter `mkdir ~/Software`, whilst ensuring the version number, 6.2.4 here, matches the version you downloaded)
4. Still using the terminal enter `mv ~/Downloads/Postman-linux-x64-6.2.4.tar.gz ~/Software` to move the file from the Downloads directory to the Software directory
5. Enter `cd ~/Software` to enter the new Software directory
6. Enter `pwd` (confirm the present working directory is `/home/<username>/Software`)
7. Enter `ls` (list files to confirm the gz file is in the folder)
8. Enter `gunzip ~/Software/Postman-linux-x64-6.2.4.tar.gz` to unzip the gzipped file
9. Enter `ls` (to confirm the tar file is now in the folder)
10. Enter `tar -xf Postman-linux-x64-6.2.4.tar.gz` to extract the files out of the tar archive.
11. Run `~/Software/Postman/Postman` (or open this link in your file manager)
12. In the terminal Enter `rm ~/Software/Postman-linux-x64-6.2.4.tar` to tidy up
13. In the long run an installation to `/opt/Postman` is a much better option (`/opt` is a 'correct' place to store software), but that approach potentially produces more complications due to the required ownership permissions