# Postman not opening on 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Installed postman from the ubuntu software centre under a fresh install and the app will not open.

This is the information from `snap list`

> postman                  7.13.0                      97    stable    postman-inc✓  -

I've tried the fix suggest [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031534/postman-not-launching-anymore-in-18-04), however that didn't work.

Madness, that this app has been chosen as the banner for software centre and doesn't work out-the-box on LTS version!

[image: software_center]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This guide will install non-snap version

1. Remove snap version

```
sudo snap remove postman
```

2. Download and install apt version

```
wget https://dl.pstmn.io/download/latest/linux64 -O postman.tar.gz

sudo tar -xzf postman.tar.gz -C /opt

rm postman.tar.gz

sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman
```

3. Make a app launcher shortcut (Paste this whole block below into terminal)

```
cat > ~/.local/share/applications/postman.desktop <<EOL
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Postman
Exec=postman
Icon=/opt/Postman/app/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
EOL
```

Then postman should be available in app menu.

ref: https://www.bluematador.com/blog/postman-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-1604

NOTE: this has been fixed with ubuntu 20.04 lts and postman works out-the-box

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Tried to invoke postman and was getting errors. Followed this thread . At least now the postman screen is visible but it's blank.

Comment: Maybe try purge the app and install again. . Or failing that try flatpak version